# My sites in a Liferay DXP 7.4 design fragment

Tags: liferay-dxp, liferay-7.4

I'm quite sure it would be easy to list "my sites" (current user site memberships) in a design fragment.

Massive web research wasn't successful.

Currently I'm using

```
[@liferay.user_personal_bar/]
```

which contains "My sites", which cannot be displayed expanded.

Which macro does the trick? Im thinking about something like

```
[#assign mysites = someUtil.someMethod()]
```

which I'd use in a custom pulldown instead of the personal bar (and - if possible - just add a logout to the my sites list).